# material-ui upgrade from 14.4 to 16.2 - hoc/selectable-enhance?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm upgrading a codebase from material-ui **0.14.4** to **0.16.2**.

I've been able to all components (so far) except:

```
material-ui/lib/hoc/selectable-enhance
```

The codebase uses it as follows:

```
var SelectContainer = require("material-ui/lib/hoc/selectable-enhance").SelectableContainerEnhance;
```

What is the equivalent in material-ui **0.16.2**?

I know it is `/List` but can't figure out the exact equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is now at material-ui/List/makeSelectable